# ctypes: Cast string to function?

Tags: python, c, casting, ctypes, metasploit

I was reading the article [Tips for Evading Anti-Virus During Pen Testing](http://pen-testing.sans.org/blog/pen-testing/2011/10/13/tips-for-evading-anti-virus-during-pen-testing) and was surprised by given Python program:

```python
from ctypes import *
shellcode = '\xfc\xe8\x89\x00\x00....'

memorywithshell = create_string_buffer(shellcode, len(shellcode))
shell = cast(memorywithshell, CFUNCTYPE(c_void_p))
shell()
```

The shellcode is shortened. Can someone explain what is going on? I'm familiar with both Python and C, I've tried read on the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes) module, but there are two main questions left:

- What is stored in `shellcode`?
  I know this has *something* to do with C (in the article it is an shellcode from Metasploit and a different notation for ASCII was chosen), but I cannot identify whether if it's C source (probably not) or originates from some sort of compilation (which?).
- Depending on the first question, what's the magic happening during the cast?

Comment: Have you ever opened an executable with an hex-editor? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at this shellcode, I toke it from [here](http://www.shell-storm.org/shellcode/files/shellcode-648.php) (it pops up a MessageBoxA):

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef void (* function_t)(void);

unsigned char shellcode[] =
    "\xFC\x33\xD2\xB2\x30\x64\xFF\x32\x5A\x8B"
    "\x52\x0C\x8B\x52\x14\x8B\x72\x28\x33\xC9"
    "\xB1\x18\x33\xFF\x33\xC0\xAC\x3C\x61\x7C"
    "\x02\x2C\x20\xC1\xCF\x0D\x03\xF8\xE2\xF0"
    "\x81\xFF\x5B\xBC\x4A\x6A\x8B\x5A\x10\x8B"
    "\x12\x75\xDA\x8B\x53\x3C\x03\xD3\xFF\x72"
    "\x34\x8B\x52\x78\x03\xD3\x8B\x72\x20\x03"
    "\xF3\x33\xC9\x41\xAD\x03\xC3\x81\x38\x47"
    "\x65\x74\x50\x75\xF4\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6F"
    "\x63\x41\x75\xEB\x81\x78\x08\x64\x64\x72"
    "\x65\x75\xE2\x49\x8B\x72\x24\x03\xF3\x66"
    "\x8B\x0C\x4E\x8B\x72\x1C\x03\xF3\x8B\x14"
    "\x8E\x03\xD3\x52\x33\xFF\x57\x68\x61\x72"
    "\x79\x41\x68\x4C\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4C\x6F"
    "\x61\x64\x54\x53\xFF\xD2\x68\x33\x32\x01"
    "\x01\x66\x89\x7C\x24\x02\x68\x75\x73\x65"
    "\x72\x54\xFF\xD0\x68\x6F\x78\x41\x01\x8B"
    "\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03\x68\x61\x67\x65\x42"
    "\x68\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x54\x50\xFF\x54\x24"
    "\x2C\x57\x68\x4F\x5F\x6F\x21\x8B\xDC\x57"
    "\x53\x53\x57\xFF\xD0\x68\x65\x73\x73\x01"
    "\x8B\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03\x68\x50\x72\x6F"
    "\x63\x68\x45\x78\x69\x74\x54\xFF\x74\x24"
    "\x40\xFF\x54\x24\x40\x57\xFF\xD0";

void real_function(void) {
    puts("I'm here");
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    function_t function = (function_t) &shellcode[0];

    real_function();
    function();
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it an hook it under any debugger, I'll use gdb:

```
> gcc shellcode.c -o shellcode
> gdb -q shellcode.exe
Reading symbols from shellcode.exe...done.
(gdb)
>
```

Disassemble the main function to see that different between calling `real_function` and `function`:

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x004013a0 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x004013a1 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x004013a3 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x004013a6 <+6>:     sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x004013a9 <+9>:     call   0x4018e4 <__main>
   0x004013ae <+14>:    movl   $0x402000,0xc(%esp)
   0x004013b6 <+22>:    call   0x40138c <real_function> ; <- here we call our `real_function`
   0x004013bb <+27>:    mov    0xc(%esp),%eax
   0x004013bf <+31>:    call   *%eax                    ; <- here we call the address that is loaded in eax (the address of the beginning of our shellcode)
   0x004013c1 <+33>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x004013c6 <+38>:    leave
   0x004013c7 <+39>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

There are two `call`, let's make a break point at `<main+31>` to see what is loaded in eax:

```
(gdb) break *(main+31)
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4013bf
(gdb) run
Starting program: shellcode.exe
[New Thread 2856.0xb24]
I'm here

Breakpoint 1, 0x004013bf in main ()
(gdb) disassemble
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x004013a0 <+0>:     push   %ebp
   0x004013a1 <+1>:     mov    %esp,%ebp
   0x004013a3 <+3>:     and    $0xfffffff0,%esp
   0x004013a6 <+6>:     sub    $0x10,%esp
   0x004013a9 <+9>:     call   0x4018e4 <__main>
   0x004013ae <+14>:    movl   $0x402000,0xc(%esp)
   0x004013b6 <+22>:    call   0x40138c <real_function>
   0x004013bb <+27>:    mov    0xc(%esp),%eax
=> 0x004013bf <+31>:    call   *%eax                    ; now we are here
   0x004013c1 <+33>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x004013c6 <+38>:    leave
   0x004013c7 <+39>:    ret
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Look at the first 3 bytes of the data that the address in eax continues:

```
(gdb) x/3x $eax
0x402000 <shellcode>:   0xfc    0x33    0xd2
(gdb)                    ^-------^--------^---- the first 3 bytes of the shellcode
```

So the CPU will `call 0x402000`, the beginning of our shell code at `0x402000`, lets disassemble what ever at `0x402000`:

```
(gdb) disassemble 0x402000
Dump of assembler code for function shellcode:
   0x00402000 <+0>:     cld
   0x00402001 <+1>:     xor    %edx,%edx
   0x00402003 <+3>:     mov    $0x30,%dl
   0x00402005 <+5>:     pushl  %fs:(%edx)
   0x00402008 <+8>:     pop    %edx
   0x00402009 <+9>:     mov    0xc(%edx),%edx
   0x0040200c <+12>:    mov    0x14(%edx),%edx
   0x0040200f <+15>:    mov    0x28(%edx),%esi
   0x00402012 <+18>:    xor    %ecx,%ecx
   0x00402014 <+20>:    mov    $0x18,%cl
   0x00402016 <+22>:    xor    %edi,%edi
   0x00402018 <+24>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0040201a <+26>:    lods   %ds:(%esi),%al
   0x0040201b <+27>:    cmp    $0x61,%al
   0x0040201d <+29>:    jl     0x402021 <shellcode+33>
   ....
```

As you see, a shellcode is nothing more than assembly instructions, the only different is in the way you write these instructions, it uses special techniques to make it more portable, for example never use a fixed address.

The python equivalent to the above program:

```
#!python

from ctypes import *

shellcode_data = "\
\xFC\x33\xD2\xB2\x30\x64\xFF\x32\x5A\x8B\
\x52\x0C\x8B\x52\x14\x8B\x72\x28\x33\xC9\
\xB1\x18\x33\xFF\x33\xC0\xAC\x3C\x61\x7C\
\x02\x2C\x20\xC1\xCF\x0D\x03\xF8\xE2\xF0\
\x81\xFF\x5B\xBC\x4A\x6A\x8B\x5A\x10\x8B\
\x12\x75\xDA\x8B\x53\x3C\x03\xD3\xFF\x72\
\x34\x8B\x52\x78\x03\xD3\x8B\x72\x20\x03\
\xF3\x33\xC9\x41\xAD\x03\xC3\x81\x38\x47\
\x65\x74\x50\x75\xF4\x81\x78\x04\x72\x6F\
\x63\x41\x75\xEB\x81\x78\x08\x64\x64\x72\
\x65\x75\xE2\x49\x8B\x72\x24\x03\xF3\x66\
\x8B\x0C\x4E\x8B\x72\x1C\x03\xF3\x8B\x14\
\x8E\x03\xD3\x52\x33\xFF\x57\x68\x61\x72\
\x79\x41\x68\x4C\x69\x62\x72\x68\x4C\x6F\
\x61\x64\x54\x53\xFF\xD2\x68\x33\x32\x01\
\x01\x66\x89\x7C\x24\x02\x68\x75\x73\x65\
\x72\x54\xFF\xD0\x68\x6F\x78\x41\x01\x8B\
\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03\x68\x61\x67\x65\x42\
\x68\x4D\x65\x73\x73\x54\x50\xFF\x54\x24\
\x2C\x57\x68\x4F\x5F\x6F\x21\x8B\xDC\x57\
\x53\x53\x57\xFF\xD0\x68\x65\x73\x73\x01\
\x8B\xDF\x88\x5C\x24\x03\x68\x50\x72\x6F\
\x63\x68\x45\x78\x69\x74\x54\xFF\x74\x24\
\x40\xFF\x54\x24\x40\x57\xFF\xD0"

shellcode = c_char_p(shellcode_data)

function = cast(shellcode, CFUNCTYPE(None))
function()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the kind of insight I was looking for. Most probably I won't develop shellcode myself and I think of embeddding assembly in Python a little weird, but now I know what's going on :)

Answer (score 3):

- `shellcode` , if I'm not mistaken, contains architecture-specific compiled code that roughly translates as a function call. (not an architecture expert, and the code is truncated...)
- Therefore, once you've created a C-style string with `create_string_buffer`, you can then fool python into thinking that it is a function with the `cast` call. Python then executes the code originally contained in `shellcode`.

There's a helpful link here: http://www.blackhatlibrary.net/Python#Ctypes

Answer (score 2):

Let us not forget that in order to have executable code, it has to be converted to a format that your machine understands. What you are doing there is providing a sequence of byte codes that can be interpreted by your machine, so you can tell your machine to execute it. You are effectively skipping the job of a compiler by providing the final byte codes; this technique is common in Just-In-Time compilers which have to create executable code while the program is running.
So, this actually have little to none relation to C (or Python, or any other language), but has a huge relation to the details of the architecture this code is expected to run at.

The first byte code there is `CLD` (0xfc) followed by a `CALL` instruction (0xe8) which makes the code jump to the address based on the offset specified in the next 4 bytes in this bytecode sequence, and so on.